# Rscript file path with space on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, r

I have Google Drive folder saved in my windows. I have created the bat file in that folder to run R through task scheduler but it's not reading the file as there is a spaece inbetween Google Drive..

```
@echo off 
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH      
Rscript C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R
cmd.exe
```

Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\lol\Google': No such file or directory

it should be the simple issue to resolve but I cant seem to find the solution. please help

Answer (score 0):

try putting quotes around the string

```
....
cmd> Rscript "C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R"
....
```

> don't forget to test that the file is really there.

```
....
cmd> dir "C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R"
....
```

.

```
....
@echo off 
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH      
Rscript "C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R"
cmd.exe
....
```